# jQuery - unmute and set volume <video>

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I want to unmute video and set volume when it plays

The HTML

```
<video autoplay muted class="recommendationVideo">
     <source src="assets/images/30 Second Demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The jQuery

```
$('.recommendationVideo').on('played', function(){
    $(this).prop('mute', false)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues in your code.

Firstly, the `played` event should be `play` and secondly, the `mute` property should be `muted`. With those corrected it works:

```js
$('.recommendationVideo').on('play', function() {
  $(this).prop('muted', false)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video muted class="recommendationVideo" controls>
  <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: okay, thanks to point out mistakes but i don't want to display `controls` and want to set on `autoplay` and when video start playing it should **unmute**.

Comment: Thanks, it works but only first time after refresh the same page it is not unmute.

Comment: but this code worked, when I played video first time it is unmute but after refresh the page video is mute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/playing_event